# How to specify your own logging messages

Tags: java, logging

At work, I was asked to find a way of creating a customised logging level system that would output to a .log file. I found a way that works really well, so I thought I'd share. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;                                          
import java.io.IOException;                                         
import java.io.PrintWriter;                                         
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;                                  
import java.util.Date;                                              
import java.util.Properties;                                        
import java.util.UUID;                                              
class FunctionLogging
{
    private String path;                                           
    private boolean appendToFile = false;                          

    public FunctionLogging(String file_path, boolean append_value)
    {
        path = file_path;                                         
        appendToFile = append_value;
    }
    public void writeToFile(int logType, String textLine) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream propFile = new FileInputStream("config.ini");
        Properties config = new Properties(System.getProperties());
        config.load(propFile);
        String tempLev = config.getProperty("loggingLevel");
        int logLevel = Integer.parseInt(tempLev);
        if(logType<=logLevel)
        {
            //This section is devoted to creating a timestamp of the instance the output string is created.
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy|HH:mm:ss:SSSSSS|");
            String timeStamp = format.format(date);
            SimpleDateFormat app = new SimpleDateFormat();
            app = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String dateApp = app.format(date);
            String temp = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            String unique = temp.substring(28);

            String[] messages = new String[4];
            messages[0]="DEBUG";
            messages[1]="INFO";
            messages[2]="Warning";
            messages[3]="FATAL";
            FileWriter logWriter = new FileWriter(path+dateApp+".log", appendToFile);
            PrintWriter loggerLines = new PrintWriter(logWriter);

            loggerLines.println(timeStamp+unique+"|"+messages[logType]+"|"+textLine);
            loggerLines.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have only set 4 possible levels, this can easily be expanded/contracted, based on the designer's preference.

To use it, type the following line into the class-level of each class that will be logged(again, this is easily changed)

```
FunctionLogging <variable of your choice = new FunctionLogget(path, true)
//true will append to the end of a file, false will overwrite it
//you will then write a line to it based on the variable you specified
<variable of your choice>.writeToFile(<custom integer>, "string action to logg");
```

Here's an example of the information printed.

```
12-03-2015|17:09:33:000056|955aacb7|DEBUG|Application Started
12-03-2015|17:09:35:000144|b967ca48|INFO|Entered helper method
12-03-2015|17:09:37:000147|bc048c7b|WARNING|Be aware, error encountered but will continue
12-03-2015|17:09:39:000149|8eb7279c|FATAL|He's dead Dave, they're all dead Dave!
```

Comment: It would be nice to get some feedback before people downvote, I added this for a customisable logging level with messages in the hopes of helping someone